# Adding your own hash in the URL breaks jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, browser-history, fragment-identifier, hashbang

I would like to use my own hash parameters in the URL, but when I do the jQuery Mobile site does not work any more. Just a blank white screen with an endless spinner. Is it true the hash is off limits to me when using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: If you're still having issues, I've created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which smoothly handles explicit URL navigation for jQM pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass parameters to internal/embedded page, jQuery Mobile does not support this feature. But there are two plugins that let you do so:

- https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params
- https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router

I advise you to read the official documentation on jQuery Mobile's Navigation Model:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

The two plugins are mentioned in the "Known limitations" section.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to disable the hashstate plugin. I'm not familiar with doing this but I think you can do this:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function (event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Basically, jQuery Mobile listens to this event and transitions to a page when the event handler for this event fires.

> Hash changes that occur independently of a click, such as when a user
>   clicks the back button, are handled through the hashchange event,
>   which is bound to the window object using Ben Alman's hashchange
>   special event plugin (included in jQuery Mobile). When a hash change
>   occurs (and also when the first page loads), the hashchange event
>   handler will send the location.hash to the $.mobile.changePage()
>   function, which in turn either loads or reveals the referenced page.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html*